# Sybase - Prepare comma separated values

Tags: sybase

I have a table in the following format:

```
CountryId  Name     City
1          India    Bangalore
1          India    Pune
2          USA      New York
3          UK       London
2          USA      Washington
```

I want output as:

```
CountryId  Name     City
1          India    Bangalore,Pune
2          USA      NewYork,Washington
3          UK       London
```

I want to basically convert cities from same country into one comma separated row.

Comment: In MySQL, the relevant function is GROUP_CONCAT.  You may find something searching with that.  You'll need to think about how the country ID column is used, though — it isn't obvious how USA maps to 2 or UK to 3.  (A Google search on 'sybase group_concat' throws up useful looking information from Sybase and Stack Overflow.)

Comment: You probably should confirm which SAP/Sybase product you're using because the SQL options vary between the various products and some functions are not available.